# How not to compile casting into enum type in C++?

Tags: c++, enums, casting

I have this "better" enum class that

1. cannot contain invalid values, and
2. cannot be used until enum value is not set explicitly,

as follows:

```
class Symmetry
{
    public:
        enum Type {
            GENERAL, SYMMETRIC, HERMITIAN,
            SKEW_SYMMETRIC, SKEW_HERMITIAN, UNINITIALIZED
        };

        Symmetry() { t_ = UNINITIALIZED }
        explicit Symmetry(Type t) : t_(t) { checkArg(t); }
        Symmetry& operator=(Type t) { checkArg(t); t_ = t; return *this; }

        operator Type() const {
            if (t_ == UNINITIALIZED) throw runtime_error("error");
            return t_;
        }

    private:
        Type t_;

        void checkArg(Type t) {
            if ((unsigned)t >= (unsigned)UNINITIALIZED)
                throw runtime_error("error");
        }
};
```

This allows me to write the following code:

```
Symmetry s1(Symmetry::SYMMETRIC);
Symmetry s2;
s2 = Symmetry::HERMITIAN;
Symmetry s3;
if (Symmetry::GENERAL == s3) // throws
```

My problem is that a compiler allows constructs such as:

```
Symmetry s1((Symmetry::Type)18); // throws
Symmetry s2;
s2 = (Symmetry::Type)18; // throws
```

I solved this problem by throwing exceptions, but I would prefer such a code not to compile at all (a compile time error). Is there a way how to manage this?

Comment: Even if you could fix the problem for compile-time constants, what if someone tried `Symmetry s1((Symmetry::Type)x);`?

Comment: Is your goal to disallow all casts from int or only to disallow casts from invalid ints?

Comment: To Oli: That's the point, I would like not to compile even this code. Somehow not to allow casting into Symmetry::Type type from any other type.

Comment: To Josh: from all ints (and all other types).

Comment: [Protect against Murphy, not Machiavelli.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/256629#256629)  Hypothetical users who arbitrarily cast your types around are much more the latter than the former.

Comment: @Fred: True, I just wanted to get rid of unnecessary exceptions throwing and still be sure that some Machiavelli wouldn't make a code using this class unsafe :). Or just wanted to know, if there is a clear solution to this problem, I'm not much experienced in C++. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Potentially a crummy solution, but it would solve your immediate problem.  Rather than having an inner enum type, define a little helper class with a private constructor, and make the outer class a friend.  Then the "enum" values can be static const members in your outer class.  Something like this:

(**DISCLAIMER: untested, so there may be various compilation issues, but you should get the idea**)

```
class Symmetry
{
public:
    class Type
    {
    private:
        Type() {};
        friend class Symmetry;
    };

    static const Type GENERAL;
    static const Type SYMMETRIC;
    static const Type HERMITIAN;
};
```

You will need some way of determining equality, but this should be fairly easy.

Comment: This. If you wanted, you could even go one step further, have a `Type` base class and derived `GENERAL`, `SYMMETRIC` etc subclasses each with a static const member dummy object. That would even allow for function overloading on the enumeration 'values' at compile-time... :)

Comment: But it would require virtual functions and reference semantics for behaviour based on runtime.

Comment: One issue I can think of is that those enums cannot then be used safely during the initialization or shutdown of the application (which is true for all globals). Using local static would alleviate this concern at the cost of requiring a function call... not sure if it's a great gain.

Answer (score 1):

My attempt using templates: (tested. However, this can be further improved!)

```
template<int N>
struct Symmetry  
{
    enum Type
    {
        GENERAL, SYMMETRIC, HERMITIAN,
        SKEW_SYMMETRIC, SKEW_HERMITIAN
    };
    template<Type e> struct allowed;
    template<> struct allowed<GENERAL>        { static const int value = GENERAL; };
    template<> struct allowed<SYMMETRIC>      { static const int value = SYMMETRIC; };
    template<> struct allowed<HERMITIAN>      { static const int value = HERMITIAN; };
    template<> struct allowed<SKEW_SYMMETRIC> { static const int value = SKEW_SYMMETRIC; };
    template<> struct allowed<SKEW_HERMITIAN> { static const int value = SKEW_HERMITIAN; };

    allowed<(Type)N> m_allowed;

    operator int()
    {
        return N;
    }
};

Symmetry<0> e0;                   //okay
Symmetry<1> e1;                   //okay
Symmetry<100> e4;                 //compilation error!
Symmetry<e0.SKEW_HERMITIAN> e3;   //okay
Symmetry<e0.SKEW_SYMMETRIC> e3;   //okay
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    Symmetry<0> e0;                   
    Symmetry<e0.HERMITIAN> e1;           

    switch (e1)
    {
    case e0.HERMITIAN:
        {
            cout << "It's working" << endl;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: With this, all Symmetry "variables" must have their value fixed at compile-time!  (Even stricter than being immutable.)  If that's what's desired, just use constants such as an enum already provides you.

Comment: @Fred : enum lets you assign other values as well. Using the above approach, you **cannot** use values other than what is "explicitly" allowed!

Comment: @Nawaz: Using the code above, could you accept user input and give it to a function which takes any valid Symmetry value?  (No.)  What is the point of a variable that does not vary?  All your code does is change the name of HERMITIAN (the enum constant I mentioned) to something else.

Comment: @Fred: the topic is *"How not to compile...."*. So it seems everything is fixed at compile time. What you're saying is true, but that is not what the topic seems to be. Furthermore, what you're saying is not about enum, as enum is about constants. You can do non-constant things using any variable!

Comment: @Nawaz: No, everything is not fixed at compile time. The user input (file input etc.) as Fred pointed out is expected. Say I open a matrix file and need to set a symmetry flag according its data. I'm sorry if it is not clear from the answer.

Comment: @Daniel: Then your topic title *"How not to compile..."* is misleading. Also what you're trying to get cannot be called enum, or enum-type-construct (since enum is compile-time constant) so you cannot use them where enum can be used, like in `case` of `switch` blocks.

Comment: @Nawaz: I can definitely use my Symmetry class in case or switch blocks, such as Symmetry s1; ... switch(s1) { case Symmetry::SYMMETRIC: ... etc. Thanks to operator Type().

Comment: @Daniel: Oh yeah.I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

No.  If you allow any cast to be used, as your last example does, then there will always be some cast that can be used to subvert your type.

The solution is to not be in the habit of using these casts and to very suspiciously consider any code that uses these casts indiscriminately.  View this type of casting as the nuclear bomb in your arsenal: it's important to have, but you always handle it with care and never want to deploy it more than rarely.

What warning options does your compiler have for casting?  What lint tools are you using which may detect this misuse of casts?

---

That said, it appears you really want to hide the inner Type so users are less tempted to even use it.  Realizing that, it's [straight-forward to make that type name private](http://ideone.com/XrZpc), even while not preventing all cast misuse, by slightly tweaking your original:

```
struct Symmetry {
  enum {
    UNINITIALIZED,
    GENERAL, SYMMETRIC, HERMITIAN,
    SKEW_SYMMETRIC, SKEW_HERMITIAN
  };

private:
  typedef decltype(UNINITIALIZED) Hidden;
  Hidden _value;

public:
  Symmetry(Hidden value = UNINITIALIZED) : _value (value) {}
  Symmetry& operator=(Hidden value) { _value = value; return *this; }
  operator Hidden() const {
    if (_value == UNINITIALIZED) {
      throw std::logic_error("uninitialized Symmetry");
    }
    return _value;
  }

  bool initialized() const { return _value != UNINITIALIZED; }
  // required if you want to check for UNINITIALIZED without throwing in
  // the above conversion
};
```

This is a complete implementation, no details omitted or unknown, or issues with initialization order.  The only caveat is decltype – with a pre-C++0x compiler, you'll have to use something implementation-specific or a [library](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/typeof.html) which wraps something implementation-specific.

And a smaller issue: change from runtime_error to logic_error, as using uninitialized values should be preventable beforehand and thus falls in the latter category.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither decltype nor BOOST_TYPEOF works (with anonymous enum). Got compiler errors, tried GNU and Intel.

Comment: @Daniel: The easiest workaround until full 0x support is to give the enum a name.  Make the name obviously non-public, like DoNotUseThis – literally that exact name.  Of course, people can still use it and you can't stop them, but the reality is the above code doesn't either.  This is why I answered as I did in the first part.